# Find the interval of convergence to $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{n}}{n(n-1)}.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My task is to find the interval of convergence to:$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n(n-1)}.$$

My work so far:

Taking $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=|x|<1\implies x\in(\pm1,).$ Now checking endpoints we see that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=0$ for $x=1$ which means convergent. Now for $x=-1$, we get: $$\frac{(-1)^n(-1)^n}{n(n-1)}=\frac{(-1)^{2n}}{n(n-1)}= \frac{1}{n(n-1)}= \frac{A}{n}+\frac{B}{n-1}.$$
Gives us $A=-1, B = 1$, which leads me to: $$\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\ldots-\frac{1}{n}.$$and if my reasoning is right $\lim_{n\to\infty}1-1/n=1.$ Which tells me it converges in both ends.

Since there are no solution to this exercise I'm wondering whether the last step is right and also perhaps someone could show me a better approach rather than partial fraction if possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the case of $-1$, it seems that you made a mistake in the first step. It should be$ (-1)^n(-1)^{2n}$ in the numerator.

Comment: @Rowan I made an error in the question, corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

Take the $\;n\,-$ th root of the whole term:

$$\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n(n-1)}\right|}=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[n]{n(n-1)}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}x^2$$

and we can see the radius of convergence is $\;R=1\;$.

Observe that for both $\;x=\pm1\;$ you get a Leibniz alternating series, and these are convergent:

$$\frac{(-1)^n(\pm1^{2n})}{n(n-1)}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n(n-1)}$$

since $\;n\,,\,\,3n\;$ have the same parity...or simpler: because $\;(\pm1)^{2n}=1\;$ in any case.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I made an error in the question, I've made an edit now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, bad mistake...but the way is practically the same as shown above, and the series **still**  converges at both extreme points, but at $\;x=-1\;$ you get a positive converging series.